# Does the subscribe method return a list after completion?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

```typescript
paraBirims: ParaBirimi[];
Get_All(adres: any): Observable < T[] > {
    return this.http.get < T[] > (this.base + "/" + adres);
}
getParaBirims(): ParaBirimi[] {
    this.genericParaBirim?.Get_All("ParaBirimis/Generic_Method").subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
            this.paraBirims = data
        },
        error: (err) => {},
        complete: () => {}
    });
}
```

I want it to give me list as return in above code(getParaBirims). How should I write?

```typescript
this.paraBirims = getParaBirims();
```

Comment: What does the `subscribe` method documentation say?

Comment: `subscribe()` returns a `Subscription` object.

Comment: There is no resource to suggest that it can be done. I was just wondering if it's possible to customize it.
I don't want to read the same list in different sources each time. I want to pull from a single typescript file and use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the `environment.ts` file to define your URL prefixes. That way you can change them based on what environment you're running the app.

As dopoto said, it is better to simply define the Observable and subscribe to it in the component. We can remove a lot of boilerplate from your code and do the following.

```
public paraBirims$: Observable<ParaBirimi[]>;

constructor(private http:HttpClient){
  this.paraBirims$ = this.http
   .get<ParaBirimi[]>(`${environment.url}/ParaBirimis/Generic_Method`);
}
```

Then in your component's TS file:

```
this.paraBirims$ = this.service.paraBirims$;
```

Lastly in your component's HTML template:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let paraBirim of paraBirims$ | async">
    <!-- do whatever with paraBirim -->
  </li>
<ul>
```

The `async` pipe will automatically handle subscribing and unsubscribing based on your component's lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Your getParaBirims() function should return a subscription, and you should consume that subscription by subscribing to it in your services and/or components or through the `async` pipe.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call `this.paraBirims = this.getParaBirims();`
you should make your method return the list and then assign it to your variable in ngOnInit hook:

```js
//changes in the method 
getParaBirims(): ParaBirimi[] {
    this.genericParaBirim?.Get_All("ParaBirimis/Generic_Method").subscribe(data => {
             return data;
        });
}

//here call the method in ngOnInit()
ngOnInit() {
   this.paraBirims = this.getParaBirims();
}
```

Or simply make the method return void:

```js
 getParaBirims():void
```

and then call it in ngOnInit()

```js
ngOnInit() {
   this.getParaBirims();
}
```